# Setting up a domain name for Frontend and Backend on XAMPP

Tags: php, html, dns, xampp

its my first time asking a question on StackOverflow.

I have a library system that includes a frontend and a backend using php. The file structure of the system has:
Root directory: thesis/
Frontend: thesis/frontend/library/index.php
Backend: thesis/backend/base/index.php

How do I make that when you type www.example.com it will redirect you to the frontend which is the thesis/frontend/library/index.php and when you type admin.example.com it will redirect to the backend which is the thesis/backend/base/index.php.

I have somehow researched something and found out creating virtual host. But cannot achieved this.

P.S.
The frontend gets resources (e.g. images) on the backend folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your virtual host to `xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

```
# Frontend
<VirtualHost example.com:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/thesis/frontend/library"
    ServerName example.com
</VirtualHost>

# Backend
<VirtualHost admin.example.com:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/thesis/backend/base"
    ServerName admin.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

now you need to add record in hosts file to resolve example.com in 127.0.0.1

open your host file `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` and add

```
127.0.0.1 example.com
127.0.0.1 admin.example.com
```

restart apache

Done

Comment: Done that, but images located on the backend folder doesnt load when retrieved on the frontend. Tried relative link (../../backend/.....image.png) and the direct link (admin.example.com/.....image.png)

Comment: You can load images from backend using absolute path, `http://admin.example.com/images/<imagename>`